# The 'fixed point theory' about the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

In fact it is about holomorphic functions:

Does every holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{D}\longrightarrow \mathbb{D}$ have a fixed point? Here $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk centered around $0$ on the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.

It is an exercise from Stein's book, Complex Analysis ,exercise 12, Chapter 8.

My idea is as follows: First extend $f$ to the closure of the unit disk $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$, i.e. $\tilde{f}:\bar{\mathbb{D}}\longrightarrow\bar{\mathbb{D}}$, $\bar{f}$ is continuous. Then apply the method of proving the classical fixed point theory on the unit disk. Yet this way we can at most get that $\bar{f}$ has fixed points,not $f$.

Are there any flaws in the above sketch of proof?

Or would someone be kind enough to give some hints on this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: The open unit disk is biholomorphic to another open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ that might be easier to work with...

Comment: If you use the hyperbolic metric, you have that holomorphic maps $F:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ do not increase distance, and because of Schwarz's Lemma, you have that a holomorphic map is either an isometry or a contraction (not necessarily strict) with this metric (you can consult Complex Analysis in the Spirit of Lipman Bers, for example).

Comment: If the contraction is strict, then you have Banach's fixed point theorem. If your function is an isometry, then it is a Moebius transformation, and you can study its fixed points in the disk. If not, then you can reduce your problem to seeing contractions that are not strict.

Comment: One flaw in our reasoning is that it is not clear that $f$ can be extended continuously to the closed disk.

Comment: Also consider the example $f(z) = (z+2)/3$

Comment: Considering GEdgar's counterexample,maybe this problem should revised to show that every holomorphic function $f:\bar{\mathbb{D}}\longrightarrow\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ has a fixed point,which becomes the classical fixed point problem.